# What is the risk with electronic contract notes in India?

Tags: india, trading, stock-markets, risk, online-trading

When you sign up for online commodity trading in India (and maybe even equities), if you opt for the convienience of electronic contract note, you are asked to sign a [declaration](http://www.mcxindia.com/membership/compliances/pdf/ClientMember/ECN.doc) that states:

> I am aware of risk involved in dispensing with the physical contract
> note, and do hereby take full responsibility for the same

What is the risk of choosing electronic notes over physical ones?

Comment: In case of a dispute over whether an electronically placed order was executed correctly, will a court or arbitrator accept your print-out of the electronic order as a legitimate order, or will it require an actual piece of paper with an ink signature?

Comment: The contract note, whether physical or electronic, is generated post order execution, isn't it? I don't think it can be used a means of verifying if an order was executed as placed. And yes digitially signed contract notes are valid legal documents under IT Act of 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The risk that you don't see it. It might end up in your spam folder, the email server might fail etc. A physical note may have a delivery receipt (courier company's counterfoil or post details) but it's very difficult to ensure delivery with e-contract-notes.
2. The risk that the note is modified before it gets to you. Physical contract notes are usually printed, and you are likely to notice modifications. E-notes can be changed (many such notes are sent as HTML in a non-encrypted zip file). Many brokers do digitally sign notes nowadays but it is no longer required.

But I think the regulation is a vestige of the past, and has mainly to do with 1) above, i.e. that they can't ensure delivery. There's no standard contract note format, or even a standard delivery mechanism either.